# Java. ArrayList. Сравнить содержимое двух листов без учета последовательности

Tags: java, массивы, циклы, arraylist

Есть 2 листа:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("a");

list.add("a");

list.add("b");

ArrayList<String> list001 = new ArrayList<String>();

list001.add("a");    

list001.add("b");

list001.add("a");
```

Необходим метод выясняющий равны ли значения их ячеек без учета их порядка и последовательности то есть эти можно считать равными = true;
Имея в виду что таких элементов может быть и много...

Можно использовать любые фичи кроме фраимворков. Может есть короткий способ, наверняка сан предусмотрел такое дело. Может кто знает?

Comment: `containsAll(Collection<?> c)` пробовали?

Comment: @MrFylypenko если у второго списка, например, убрать один из "a" (например последний), то containsAll покажет true все равно

Comment: Не знал про этот метод спасибо!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский верно, покажет true, но он не будет сортировать массивы и надеюсь решит поставленные задачи. Ваш вариант мне тоже нравится.

Comment: Алексей Шиманский  да действительно не заметил...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как вариант сортируем коллекции и сравниваем их:

```
Collections.sort(list);
Collections.sort(list001);
System.out.println(list.equals(list001));
```

должно помочь

Answer (score 2):

если отсортировать списки нельзя, можно подсчитать количество вхождений каждого элемента в список и сравнить:

```
List<String> first = Arrays.asList( "a", "b", "a" );
List<String> second = Arrays.asList( "a", "a", "b" );

// используется import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
//   иначе это еще страшнее выглядит
first.stream().collect( groupingBy( k -> k, counting()) )
    .equals( second.stream().collect( groupingBy( k -> k, counting()) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Может я до конца не понял сути вопроса, но если есть необходимость сравнить между собой каждый элементо по отдельности, то можно попробовать такой метод:

```
public static void compareTwoLists(ArrayList list, ArrayList list2){
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++){
            if(list.get(i).equals(list2.get(j)) == true){
                System.out.println("Элемент " + i + 
                        " первого массива равен элементу " + j + " второго массива.");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Элемент " + i + 
                        " первого массива не равен элементу " + j + " второго массива.");
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для сравнения двух коллекций можно использовать HashSet.

В моём примере нужно было сравнить два списка объектов, я сделал это по их уникальному ID (вместо Integer может быть и String, как в вашем примере).

```
    Set<Integer> objectsIds = new HashSet<>();

    for (Object object : objectList1) {
        objectsIds.add(object.getId());
    }

    for (Object object : objectList2) {
        if (objectsIds.contains(object.getId())) {
            objectsIds.remove(object.getId());
        } else {
            objectsIds.add(object.getId());
        }
    }
```

На выходе получаем сет, который пуст, если коллекции одинаковые, в противном случае - получаем разницу.

Проверка:

```
objectsIds.isEmpty();
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать с помощью метода:

```
    list.containsAll(list001);
```

Удалить совпадения с помощью:

```
    list.removeAll(list001);
```

И удалить различающиеся элементы с помощью:

```
    list.retainAll(list001);
```